# Selenium send_keys alternative?

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard

Hello fellow programmers, I'm using selenium to submit a form.
On all of the inputs send_keys is working perfectly. But there's an otp verification Input if i use send_keys it triggers a function to send another otp code via email and the page starts loading again ...
Can't find any function callback on the  div but that's the way it works, if i type it from my keyboard it works.
Solutions i implemented :

1 - I made this function to work around it but it didn't help.

```
def keyTrans(cod):
    str = ''
    for c in cod:
        str = str + 'keys.Keys.NUMPAD{}/'.format(c)
    L=str.split('/')
    print(L)
    return L
```

2 - I used pynput lib

```
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(otp)).click()
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.type(str(code))
```

Both solutions ended up in causing the browser to load and send another otp ...
Any of you have seen something like this before ? or do you suggest anything else to try ?
Also as i mentioned i didn't find the fn callback on this otp input so i can't be 100% sure that keyboard is causing it but most likely it is since whenever i type it from my keyboard it works just fine .

[image: That's the HTML the otp input is causing the problem]

Comment: Can you show the HTML and the original code you tried ?

Comment: Maybe try setting the value through driver.execute_script.

Comment: Added the html .
The code first implementation was like this : browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'otp').send_keys(otp)

Comment: @ArundeepChohan If you could post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the text using the `ActionChains`.
You will need to import

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Initialize the `actions` object with

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

Get the web element, let's call it "input"

```py
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='otp']")
```

and then perform click and "send_keys" with the

```py
actions.move_to_element(input).click().send_keys(your_text).perform()
```

Comment: I Actually used action chains to send the keys before, same problem. The page loads again that's when i concluded send_keys was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1];', op, code)`
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan comment, with op being the otp element and code obviously the extracted otp code.

Worth to mention i tried different other ways of implementing the script and all failed .
`driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("otp").value = "{code}";')`
`driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("otp").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(code))`
and other variations that i deleted